# YII2 : Can we configure session setting without using configuration file (main.php)

Tags: database, session, yii2

Following configuration should be in main.php under session array.

```
 'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
      'sessionTable' => 'session',
```

Can we configure these settings outside of config folder or anywhere in yii2. ?

Comment: What's the use case for that? Could you provide more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure confi array or session param    when you want

for config array you can access config or use the component/section related configuration function

for session like in Yii2 Guide you can

> ```
> $session = Yii::$app->session;
>
> // get a session variable. The following usages are equivalent:
> $language = $session->get('language');
> $language = $session['language'];
> $language = isset($_SESSION['language']) ? $_SESSION['language'] : null;
>
> // set a session variable. The following usages are equivalent:
> $session->set('language', 'en-US');
> $session['language'] = 'en-US';
> $_SESSION['language'] = 'en-US';
> ```

in your case

```
 $session->set('sessionTable', 'session');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html

Comment: Thank you @scais it helped me.